# How to URL encode all my data

Tags: django

My gateway say I need to URL encode all my data, in Django how is this possible?

```
requests.post(default_gateway.keyword_forwarding_url, data=raw_data,
                                     stream=True, verify=True)
```

I have tried

```
import urllib
requests.post(default_gateway.keyword_forwarding_url, data=urllib.urlencode(raw_data),
                                     stream=True, verify=True)
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried it?

Comment: What the status on this... did you get things resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Your data needs to be passed to urlencode() as a dict or in a sequence of paired tuples:

```
import urllib
formatted_raw_data = {raw_data[0]: raw_data[1], raw_data[2]: raw_data[3]} // or however it needs to be formatted
requests.post(default_gateway.keyword_forwarding_url, data=urllib.urlencode(formatted_raw_data),
                                     stream=True, verify=True)
```